# Django logging - ValueError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: django, linux, ubuntu, logging, virtualbox

I am trying to configure some logging within an application that uses Django that will ultimately log a few different types of information to separate log files (such as time taken to run a module, markers for different modules to categorize flow, etc).

The application is deploying to a VirtualBox Ubuntu 16.04 environment.

Right now, I'm simply trying to get some simple test information logged into a file called eems-dashboard.log (which I created, is empty, and seem to have full access to) just to try to get the logging to work initially. The setup in settings.py looks like this:

```
LOGGING = {
   'version': 1,
   'disable_existing_loggers': False,
   'formatters': {
       'verbose': {
           'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
       },
   },
   'handlers': {
       'console': {
           'level': 'DEBUG',
           'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
           'formatter': 'verbose'
       },
       'log_file':{
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'filename': '/var/log/eems-dashboard.log',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        }
   },
   'loggers': {
       '': {
           'handlers': ['log_file'],
           'level': 'DEBUG',
       },
       'django.request': {
           'handlers': ['log_file'],
           'propagate': True,
           'level': 'DEBUG'
       },
       'apps': {
            'handlers': ['log_file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        }
   }
}
```

However, whenever I try to run a local deployment of this application, I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/webapps/uiux/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/webapps/uiux/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/webapps/uiux/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 22, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/webapps/uiux/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 75, in configure_logging
    logging_config_func(logging_settings)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/config.py", line 795, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/config.py", line 566, in configure
    '%r: %s' % (name, e))
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'log_file': 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I have found some limited information on this error, but none of the solutions seem to apply to the problem at hand. I've allowed full permissions to the file path for the log file, but that's all the troubleshooting advice I was able to find. I'm pretty sure it has to do with the syntax of the LOGGING configuration and not an issue with any of the other modules that appear in the error. I am very new to programming/developing in general for context. Thank you.

Comment: why your first logger is empty string?

Comment: @Saeed I don't believe that empty string would matter. The handler in question is `'log_file'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to specify a class for that `log_file` handler. I dug into Python's logging/config.py module and it attempts to find a class key in the given config before calling `split()` on said key. As you did not specify a class key in your `log_file` dict, it will attempt to call `split()` on `None`.

e.g.

`'log_file':{
    'level': 'DEBUG',
    'filename': '/var/log/eems-dashboard.log',
    'formatter': 'verbose',
    'class': 'logging.handlers.SysLogHandler'
}`

Check out the docs to see which logging handler is right for you.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html